# Why Does Prisma Not Recognize Optional Fields When Using TypeScript Spread Operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, javascript-objects, prisma

I am working with NestJS, Prisma, and TypeScript, and I encountered an unexpected behavior related to optional fields in Prisma schema when creating a new record. The issue seems to arise when using the TypeScript spread operator for optional fields.

```
model Room {
  id           Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String       @db.VarChar()
  roomType     String       @db.VarChar()
  propertyId   Int
  surfaceArea  Float
  // ... other fields
}
```

In the schema, surfaceArea is an optional field.

```
export class CreateRoomBodyDto {
  // ... other fields
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  surfaceArea?: number;
}
```

Service Method:
When I use the spread operator for roomDetails from the DTO in Prisma's create method, Prisma seems to ignore the optional surfaceArea field:

```
public async createRoom(roomData: CreateRoomBodyDto): Promise<CreateRoomResponse> {
  const { facilities, ...roomDetails } = roomData;

  const room = await this.prismaClient.room.create({
    data: { ...roomDetails }
  });

  // ... other logic
}
```

However, when I explicitly set surfaceArea: roomDetails.surfaceArea in the create method, it works as expected:

```
const room = await this.prismaClient.room.create({
  data: { ...roomDetails, surfaceArea: roomDetails.surfaceArea },
});
```

Question:
Why does Prisma not recognize or properly handle the optional surfaceArea field when using the TypeScript spread operator? Is there a specific reason related to TypeScript's type inference or Prisma's handling of optional fields?

I am trying to understand the underlying cause of this behavior to better structure my data handling in NestJS with Prisma and TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Designate a type to the roomDetails variable when you are assigning a value to it. This way Prisma is able to work with types and will properly handle all the fields.